# Start from left in fancycoverflow

Tags: android, center, coverflow

I am using [fancycoverflow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) in my project.
It displays the first item at centre, but I want it to display from the left side. Suppose I want 5 items to be displayed on screen, then the 1st item should be the left most item, and the 3rd item should be selected and at the centre position.

Comment: What have you tried and where does it not work? This is not a 'please write my code' site. Please [edit] your question and put in your code modifications, error messages etc.